# metrics for a dApp

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, dapps, web3.py

I am writing an academic paper for a particular blockchain application and trying to compare it to other existing solutions (which are also on blockchain)

I desperately require some measurable functional or performance metrics that I can measure

I will then use these metrics to compare my DApp to other existing solutions ( i can simulate the other solutions and their metrics as well )

If someone can name any measurable / quantifiable performance metrics, i would be grateful !

Answer (score 1):

Here are some blockchain decentralization metrics. These include the Nakomoto coefficient, Lorenz curve, Gini coefficient, Herfindahl-Hirschman index, and Theil L/T index.

See: https://www.smartcontractresearch.org/t/notable-works-in-decentralization-metrics/828

Other blockchain metrics include Active Nodes, Blocks Per Hour, Blocks Per Day, Transactions Per Second, Transaction Latency, Transaction Throughput, and Full Node/Partial Node Ratio.

See: https://patterns.arcitura.com/blockchain-patterns/blockchain-metrics